# jBox doesn't show notice

Tags: javascript

I've got a js script on my checkbox but message doesn't come

```
$('.js__test').on('change', function () {
        const url = $(this).data('url');
        let data;
        if (this.checked) {
            data = '1';
        } else {
            data = '0';
        }
        $.post(url, data, function (data, status) {
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                new jBox("Notice", {
                    color: 'green',
                    content: 'success',
                });
            })
    });
```

But if I use variable definition it works

```
 var v = new jBox("Notice", {
                    color: 'green',
                    content: 'success',
                   });
                v.open();
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: @Satpal ...Post it as an answer? :S

Comment: @Satpal In this case I see white message at the center of the screen. It should work without .open(). And I ask how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't included the script and css file for notice. Please include this tag in your page

```
<script src="//code.jboxcdn.com/plugins/Notice/jBox.Notice.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jboxcdn.com/plugins/Notice/jBox.Notice.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myNotice').click(function() {
    new jBox('Notice', {
      content: 'Hurray! A notice!',
      color: 'blue'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jboxcdn.com/0.4.8/jBox.min.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jboxcdn.com/0.4.8/jBox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.jboxcdn.com/plugins/Notice/jBox.Notice.js"></script>
<link href="//code.jboxcdn.com/plugins/Notice/jBox.Notice.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="cursor: pointer" id='myNotice'>Just a div</div>
```

Comment: In this case I see white message at the center of the screen. It should work without .open(). And I ask how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `open()`?

Comment: As I said, it shows just white message at the center of the screen and don't destroy itself after some time

Comment: Just created a demo app, you just need to include css and js file of notice. Just try it once and let me know. Updated the solution.

Comment: Yes, now it's blue. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Just went through documentation and luckily stumbled on notice demo. Somehow, managed to find the error.